# Objective c - Multiple colors in a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring

What is the easiest way to have a label with different colors?

For example I want to present the message:
"John Johnson sent you a message"

But I want that `John Johnson` will be in **blue** color
and the rest of the message in **black** color.

Comment: I'd raise this as a bug with Apple. We really ought to be able to use attributed strings in iOS. Fingers crossed they include it in a future release.

Comment: *cough* look at the iOS6 docs *cough*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UILabel basically impossible. If you want to this you must override `drawTextInRect` should be executed. But I will recommend [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/). this is have a attributedString is a textcolor can be set to specify a range.

Comment: Thanks I'll go with your solution :)

Answer (score 4):

You need the `NSAttributedString` class (or the mutable one - `NSMutableAttributedString`) in order to set attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string *and* a custom label control that can visualize `NSAttributedString` like [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UIWebView`.

```
webView.text = 
  @"<span style:\"color:blue;\">John Johnson</span> sent you a message.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CoreText](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created an UILabel extension to do this. Basically what it does is use NSAttributedString to define the color for some particular range: https://github.com/joaoffcosta/UILabel-FormattedText

If you wish to implement this behavior yourself, just do the following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: @"John Johnson sent you a message"];
[text addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
             value: font
             range: range];
[self setAttributedText: text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with swift (execute code with following extension)

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColorForText(textToFind: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Try an extension with UILabel:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 280, height: 200)
let stringValue = "John Johnson sent you a message"  // or direct assign single string value like "firstsecondthird"
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
label.numberOfLines = 0
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColorForText(textToFind: "John Johnson", withColor: UIColor.blue)
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Here is result:

[image]